# If the relation $f(x_1, ..., x_n)=y$ is $\Sigma_1$, then is its negation also $\Sigma_1$?

Tags: logic, recursion, computability, peano-axioms

If the relation $f(x_1, ..., x_n)=y$ is $\Sigma_1$, then is its negation also $\Sigma_1$?

The above question (ore more like the imperative to prove it in the affirmative) is Exercise 1. on page 54 of Smullyan's *Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems*, and it would show that every $\Sigma_1$-function is recursive. He gives the 'hint' that if $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is unequal to $y$, then it is equal to some number other than $y$.

Now I understand that the hint hints at a solution where you do not just negate the $\Sigma_1$-formula that expresses $f(x_1, ..., x_n)=y$, since that would no longer be $\Sigma_1$, as $\exists v_{n+2}(v_1, ..., v_n, v_{n+1}, v_{n+2})$ expresses $f(x_1, ..., x_n)=y$ , and its negation would be $\forall v_{n_2}\neg (v_1, ..., v_n, v_{n+1}, v_{n+2})$, which is an unbounded universal quantifier.

But this is where I'm stuck. It seems to me that if we want to express that $f(x_1, ..., x_n)= u$, where $u \neq y$, then we would always need to have a formula in which $y$ occurs free, which would then have too many free variables to express an $n+1$-ary relation, since we have to have $x_1, ..., x_n$ and $u$ free as well.

More specifically, we could take the formula $\exists v_{n+2}(v_1, ..., v_n, v_{n+1}, v_{n+2}) \wedge v_{n+3} \neq v_{n+1}$, which would then express $g(x_1, ..., x_n)=(y,u)$ where $f(x_1,..., x_n)=y$ and $\neg f(x_1, ..., x_n)=u$, or more precisely, $g(x_1, ..., x_n, y)=u$. But what we need is $g(x_1, ..., x_n)=u$.

Could the formula be $\exists v_{n+1}(\exists v_{n+2}(v_1, ..., v_n, v_{n+1}, v_{n+2}) \wedge v_{n+3} \neq v_{n+1})$? This would be true *iff* there is a number $k$ such that $\exists v_{n+2}(v_1, ..., v_n, \overline{k}, v_{n+2}) \wedge v_{n+3} \neq \overline{k}$, which in turn would be true for any numbers $k_1, ..., k_n$ such that $f(k_1, ..., k_n)=k$ and $u\neq k$.

[Of course this isn't technically a *regular* formula since $v_{n+1}$ is bound, while $v_{n+3}$ is free, so by definition, it does not express any relation.

The definitions are this:

- A regular formula $F$ is such that for any $i$, if $v_i$ is a free
  variable of $F$, then for any $j \leq i$, $v_j$ is also a free
  variable of $F$.
- A regular formula $F(v_1,...,v_n)$ *expresses* the set of all
  $n$-tuples $(k_1, ..., k_n)$ of natural numbers such that
  $F(\overline{k_1}, ..., \overline{k_n})$ is a true sentence.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is a function, then:

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n) \neq y \iff \exists z\, (f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = z \land z \neq y).$$

More precisely, if $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = y$ is expressed by the $\Sigma_1$-formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$, then $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) \neq y$ is expressed by the formula $\exists z\, (\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n,z)\land (z\neq y))$, which is also $\Sigma_1$ (since $z\neq y$ is quantifier-free, hence $\Sigma_1$, and the $\Sigma_1$ formulas are closed under conjunction and existential quantifiers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I understand correctly, my formula at the end was right, but I'll have to play around with the variables to make it regular.

Comment: @susypeti To be honest, I'm really confused by your notation. When you write $\exists v_{n+2}\, (v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1},v_{n+2})$, I guess you mean $\exists v_{n+2}\, \varphi(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, where $\varphi$ is a $\Delta_0$ (bounded) formula?

Comment: Also, note that a $\Sigma_1$-formula can have multiple existential quantifiers, not just one. So in general, $f(v_1,\dots,v_n) = v_{n+1}$ will be expressed by a formula of the form $\exists v_{n+2}\dots v_{n+k}\, \varphi(v_1,\dots,v_{n+k})$, where $\varphi$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula.

Comment: Then yes, it's just a matter of rearranging the variables to make the formula regular, if you care about that. Using the $\Sigma_1$-formula in my last comment to express $f$, we can write $$\exists v_{n+k+1}\, (\exists v_{n+2}\dots v_{n+k}\, \varphi(v_1,\dots,v_{n},v_{n+k+1}, v_{n+2},\dots, v_{n+k}) \land v_{n+k+1}\neq v_{n+1}).$$

Comment: So this is Smullyan's notation that I copied, and in his definition, $\Sigma_1$ has one and only one existential quantifier at the beginning, which flanks a $\Sigma_0$ formula (only bounded quantifiers, if any), so that is why I've always included $\exists v_{n+2}$ before $F(v_1, ..., v_n, v_{n+1}, v_{n+2})$. I think he uses $\Sigma$ for what you call $\Sigma_1$, and then he proves that they are actually equivalent. This is my first time reading about these things so I only know what I've read so far. Thanks for your help explaining it!

Comment: @susypeti I see. Smullyan is making an unusual choice here, but it's true that in the context of a "foundational" theory (like arithmetic or set theory), the two notions are equivalent